# How to create custom radio button that is centered?

Tags: android, xamarin, mono, radio-button, xamarin.android

I am trying to create a custom centralized button. Everything works except that the button is always aligned to the left. How do I make the radio button to be centered?

NB: I am doing this with Xamarin Android in C#.

What I currently have and what I am trying to achieve is attached.

[image]

[image]

This is the AXML of the border

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
  <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/lightGreenColor" />
  <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="5dp" android:right="5dp"    android:bottom="5dp" />
</shape>
```

This is my code:

```
List<Telco> telcoList = new     GeneralUtilities().getTelcosByCountry(getApp().selectedCountry.country_code);
        RadioGroup.LayoutParams lps;
        int counter = 0;
        foreach(var telcoItem in telcoList)
        {
            counter++;
            Drawable bitt = null;
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(this);
            rb.Id = counter;
            rb.SetButtonDrawable(null);
            IObservable<IBitmap> x = new GeneralUtilities().returnImage(telcoItem.country_img,48,48);
            x.Subscribe(new Action<Splat.IBitmap>(pic => {
                bitt = BitmapMixins.ToNative(pic);
                Drawable normalDrawable = bitt;
                Drawable focusedDrawable = bitt;

                StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
                stateListDrawable.AddState(new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.StateChecked, -Android.Resource.Attribute.StatePressed }, focusedDrawable);
                stateListDrawable.AddState(new int[] { -Android.Resource.Attribute.StateChecked, -Android.Resource.Attribute.StatePressed }, normalDrawable);
                stateListDrawable.AddState(new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.StateChecked, Android.Resource.Attribute.StatePressed }, focusedDrawable);
                stateListDrawable.AddState(new int[] { -Android.Resource.Attribute.StateChecked, Android.Resource.Attribute.StatePressed }, normalDrawable);



                rb.SetButtonDrawable(stateListDrawable);
            }), ex => Console.WriteLine("Na " + ex));

            StateListDrawable state = new StateListDrawable();
            state.AddState(new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.StateChecked, -Android.Resource.Attribute.StatePressed }, Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.item_border));
            state.AddState(new int[] { -Android.Resource.Attribute.StateChecked, -Android.Resource.Attribute.StatePressed }, Resources.GetDrawable(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent));
            state.AddState(new int[] { Android.Resource.Attribute.StateChecked, Android.Resource.Attribute.StatePressed }, Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.item_border));
            state.AddState(new int[] { -Android.Resource.Attribute.StateChecked, Android.Resource.Attribute.StatePressed }, Resources.GetDrawable(Android.Resource.Color.Transparent));
            rb.SetBackgroundDrawable(state);

            lps = new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(0, RadioGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
            lps.Weight = 1;
            lps.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
            lps.SetMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);

            rb.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center;
            telcoRadioGroup.AddView(rb, lps);
        }
```

Comment: What have you tried? I don't see any AXML or code to support your question.

Comment: @Cheesebaron i am doing this dynamically as I am getting the images from a server. I have edited the question with the AXML.